# How can I change the date format from my MySQL database in my query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a webpage that has a table. I already have data from MySQL Database. I used an `INNER JOIN` because I get data of two databasetables but I want to get one more column from `milestone_parts` table.

The name of the column is `datum`(which stands for date) and the type of that column is `datetime`.
An example of a date in my database is: `2011-09-16 00:00:00`
I get that date when I print in my table of webpage. But I want to format the date from `2011-09-16 00:00:00` into `16-09-2011`.

I tried this in my query: `(DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%d-%m-%Y'))`

The content of my webpage table will dissapear, what did I wrong?

I used this query to get data from two databse tables:

```
$querySF = " SELECT  
             a.id AS `milestone_id`,
             a.titel AS `milestone_titel`,

             b.id AS `milestonefase_id`,
             b.titel AS `milestonefase_titel`,
             b.DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `milestonefase_datum`,

             FROM `milestones` a
             INNER JOIN `milestone_parts` b ON a.id=b.milestone_id
             WHERE a.verkocht_id = '{$_COOKIE['project']}' AND b.milestone_id != '' ";
```

A solution of my problem will make my day better!
Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't Format the date in SQL. You sould dou it in the php code. Because formating should be done by the view. Not by the db layer

Comment: but when I dont use  `INNER JOIN`, I get the result. Since I use `INNER JOIN`, my content of my table will dissaper

Comment: what does `inner join` have to do with format of date?

Comment: Because i need to format my ‘datum’ of database table ‘milestone_parts’

Comment: you should write like this: `DATE_FORMAT(b.datum, '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'milestonefase_datum',`

Comment: Thank you sir, this worked!, Could you please add this comment to answer section? because i will mark it as solved. Thanks! @Harshil

Comment: I have a little question. Why do I get downvotes? Did I wrote it so bad or are they only negative?

Comment: Well, it depends on user's mindset. If I found that details are insufficient or approach of Op doesn't make sense, then I'll prefer to comment it out. While some users prefer to downvote and then comment. And then there are people who just downvote posts without giving any sort of explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Harshil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$querySF = " SELECT  
             a.id AS `milestone_id`,
             a.titel AS `milestone_titel`,

             b.id AS `milestonefase_id`,
             b.titel AS `milestonefase_titel`,
             DATE_FORMAT(b.datum, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `milestonefase_datum`,  //Syntax corrected

             FROM `milestones` a
             INNER JOIN `milestone_parts` b ON a.id=b.milestone_id
             WHERE a.verkocht_id = '{$_COOKIE['project']}' AND b.milestone_id != '' ";
```

Comment: Thanks sir!, this is what I asked